# Time constants to include in Transfer function derivation of third-order filter using the FACTs method

Tags: filter, transfer-function

Concerning the problem of calculating the transfer function of a third-order filter; see *[Help deriving the transfer function of an LC circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496232/help-deriving-the-transfer-function-of-an-lc-circuit)*

A method kindly explained by Verbal Kint is 'FACTs', which takes the grind out of the process. This method requires the derivation of time constants, and includes nulling the input, setting a reactive component to either a DC or a high frequency state and finding the resistances driving the other components.

The time constants that were included are:

tau1, tau2, tau3,
tau12, tau13, tau23, tau32,
tau123

My question is, would there not be more time constants to include, for example, tau132, tau 231, etc.? I'm unsure why an exhaustive set isn't included.

I'm pretty new to this subject, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Paul, Basso has a new book out, just last December, called *The Fast Track to Determining Transfer Functions of Linear Circuits: The Student Guide*. It's a paperback and is a `workbook` format that looks a lot like his posts here, just repeated for lots of examples. (I'm holding it in my hand.) For extensive practice to deepen ideas and develop `muscle memory` of sorts, this paperback is perhaps the better one. However, it won't answer questions like "Why this and not that?" For more of that, you may need to go back to Middlebrook, himself. Or wait here for Basso...

Comment: Thanks, Periblepsis. I'm looking at it on E-Bay now..

Comment: For comparison, you can look at the site that Basso provided me at [Stairway Press](https://stairwaypress.com/product/fast-track/).

Comment: Excellent, thanks.

Comment: Hello @Paul and *periblepsis*, yes, there are redundant time constants that can be expressed from a given configuration. I call it *reshuffling* meaning that many different possible combinations exist, all leading to the same time constant. And that is cool if the first attempt brings a complicated arrangement in which inspection is difficult, you can think of a different combination leading to a simpler circuit. You may want to check this [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) also.